# How to solve Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'length' is null or not an object?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, calendar

I am using the following flat calendar control to populate my textboxes with date.

http://www.dynarch.com/static/jscalendar-1.0/simple-1.html.

I am using the validator controls for the textboxes to which i specified the calendar control. The two textboxes are used to enter the start date and end date. I have used the regex,compare validators for these textboxes.

On selecting the date in the calendar control i am receiving the following error in ie 7 aswell fireox 6+.

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'length' is null or not an object**

[alt text http://jquery-datepicker.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=3202011142275994660&name=NetRequiredFieldValidorJScriptErrorWithDatePicker.png&token=ce70cac3550ec65b48aa12d7835e2fdb&inline=1](http://jquery-datepicker.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=3202011142275994660&name=NetRequiredFieldValidorJScriptErrorWithDatePicker.png&token=ce70cac3550ec65b48aa12d7835e2fdb&inline=1)

How can i solve this prob?can anyone pls help me on this?

Comment: Check first whether length exists or not as property/method of the control

Comment: You need to locate this line - and post here the code to see why this is not an object - probably you have miss something to include or declare.

Comment: wow, I must be behind the times, I only have Firefox 3.6.8...

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#txtRegUpdateDate").datepicker({ onSelect: function() { },
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                maxLength: 10,
                regex: /^[0,1]?\d{1}\/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))\/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))$/,
                regexp: /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/
            });
```

Comment: You may want to explain your answer for the benefit of the OP.